# Error with getting variable from other script in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code of the class I want to get variable **Speed** from (attached with **Player** Object)

```
public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float Speed;

void Update()
   { 
     InvokeRepeating ("RaiseSpeed", 1.0f, 1.5f);
   }

void RaiseSpeed() { Speed += Speed/10; }

}
```

And this is the code of the class in which I want to use **Speed**

```
public class ScoreManager :MonoBehaviour
{
  public Text TextScore;
  public PlayerManager _PlayerManager;
  private int Score;

void Start()
  {
     Score = 0;
     _PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>;
     //Which is why cause error
  }

void LateUpdate()
  {
     InvokeRepeating("UpdateScoreText", 0.0f, 1.0f);
  }

void UpdateScoreText()
  {
     Score += _PlayerManager.Speed /10;
     TextScore.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString()
  }
}
```

The Error description: Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'PlayerManager'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: If it's solved, then choose the post that you want as an answer (check mark), to (a) give credit to the person that took the effort to answer, and (b) to let other readers know that this has really been solved and which one the answer is. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

`_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<GameManager>;` You tried to get GameManager instead of PlayerManager

Comment: Also need to call method of:  _PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<GameManager> **()**;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<GameManager> as PlayerManager;
```

**Updated:**

```
_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent("PlayerManager") as PlayerManager;
```

where PlayerManager is name of component in object where is PlayerManager script

Comment: Ok, thanks
just realize need to fix

`_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>`

And the code still have that error :V

Comment: try:`_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager> ();`

Comment: what component name for PlayerManager  ? you should get this component by name like this: GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent("PlayerManager") as PlayerManager;

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>;
```

with

```
_PlayerManager = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
```